# JVectorMap: drill-down for custom regions

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

Is there a way to make combined map which could use ["drill-down"](http://jvectormap.com/examples/drill-down/) behaviour for some areas and ["select"](http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/) behaviour for other ones areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you are asking can be achieved also with some of the standard functionalities provided by jVectorMap. In my example below, all US regions other than Texas can be selected, whereby the normal multimap drill-down is performed  just only for US-TX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  new jvm.MultiMap({
    container: $('#map'),
    maxLevel: 1,
    main: {
      map: 'us_lcc',
      regionsSelectable: true,
      regionStyle: {
        selected: {
            fill: 'green'
          }
        },
        onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
          if(code == "US-TX") {
            return false;
          } else {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          }
        }
      }
  });
});
```

**Explanation:**

As the documentation says [here](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-multimap/), the main Map of the MultiMap object can be configured the same way as the "normal" Map.

Inside the multi-map `onRegionClick` handler, the region selection can be avoided by returning `false`, and the drilldown can be stopped by invoking `stopImmediatePropagation()`. I tested this snippet with jVectorMap version 2.0.2 but it should work also with the latest versions.

BTW, thanks to [bjornd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367960/bjornd) for the great jVectorMap.

Comment: Cool advice. I've tried to stop event by `stopPropagation` and it wasn't work, so your solution quite clear and easy, thak you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standart behaviour to reach this.

To handle this I had to modify `MultiMap` file. In `addMap` function you could add 
hardcode check region code or add it to config and pass or deny drilling down.